# "Memory Error" - Kmeans in python using pandas DataFrame

Tags: machine-learning, python, clustering, pandas, k-means

I am trying to predict on my "dataset_to_predict" having size of (297000 x 5120). While Memory usage is under 50%. No Specific Error message.

I'm trying to find # of k using elbow method - Got MemoryError:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans, MiniBatchKMeans
km = KMeans(n_clusters=5)
k_range = range(1,10)
sse = []
for k in k_range:
    km = KMeans(n_clusters=k).fit(dataset_to_predict) #this line throw error
    #km = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=k, batch_size=100, verbose=1).fit(dataset_to_predict) #Also tried on part of the dataset
    sse.append(km.inertia_)
```

Also, I tried to use Kmeans.fit_predict() method again get the memoryError:

```
y_predicted = km.fit_predict(dataset_to_predict) #this line throws error
y_predicted
```

System Specs I have:

- Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
- Memory: 16 GB
- Swap: 2GB
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-7500 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 4

Comment: Try initializing the KMeans object first and then calling the fit method: 
km = KMeans(n_clusters=k)
km.fit(dataset_to_predict)

Comment: I notice you imported minibatch kmeans - is there a reason you dont use that? Also, how are you determining your memory usage? Are there other items running?

Comment: @flyingmeatball i used minibatch but commented it out later, and i determine the memory usage from system monitor.

Comment: @AffableAmbler it doesnt make any difference, though after reducing the sample to 30,000 it works with 90% memory consumption. Seems like i dont have the powerful machine to process 300M records!

Comment: @MGM Oh...you have 300M? Your post says 300K...

Comment: Yeah also 5,100 dimensions is a lot for kmeans. Maybe you could try to extract some principal components.

Comment: PCA doesn't work at this scale either. K-means probably neither though. The elbow method certainly won't give good results. You probably have to think more about the actual problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: @flyingmeatball oh its a typo its **300K** records. Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: @Anony-Mousse all those 5120 features are binary feature vectors, which i have encoded using one hot Encoder from few categorical features! Do you think i should apply PCA?

Comment: You're starting to get into the scale where I would consider a distributed solution - have you considered Apache Spark?

Comment: Yes there is a high likelyhood for Apache spark! But i am not sure how to use it.

Comment: No. I have seen only bad results with PCA on binary vectors coming from one-hot encoded variables. The data ends up looking like a cone usually, and there are no clusters to be found.